# How to use Nemerle in msbuild/MonoDelevep project files

Tags: msbuild, monodevelop, nemerle

I have a project which (for reasons beyond my control) uses MonoDevelop's build system. I'm unfamiliar with its build system, but I understand it IS the msbuild project format.

I can include Nemerle sources by invoking the Nemerle compiler as a separate pre-build step, but that means I have to manually keep all compiler settings/switches/defines/etc in sync between both the msbuild project files and the Nemerle compiler command line. Obviously, that's problematic.

How can I set up my project's msbuild project files to include Nemerle sources and *correctly* invoke the Nemerle compiler?